# Rails - How to customize required params for certain controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Controller with a few methods. I would like to be able to require certain parameters for certain routes.

I would like `my_endpoint_1` to not require any parameters, but for `my_endpoint_2` to 
return something like a 400 error when the `myId` parameter is not incldued.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_endpoint_1
    do_something
  end

  def my_endpoint_2
    id = params[:myId]
    do_something_with id
  end
end
```

The route for the `my_endpoint_2` is configured in my `routes.rb`:

```
get 'mycontroller/my_endpoint_2/:myId'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `myId` parameter is not provided, the route will not match and rails will therefore return a 404 NOT FOUND when in production.

As such, the end point already requires that parameter. However, both end points allow arbitrary parameters to be provided (e.g. via `mycontroller/my_endpoint_2/5?my_param=5`) but as they will be ignored, it shouldn't pose a problem. But as you asked specifically for an error message in such cases, here is one approach you can take:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_endpoint_1
    return if render_400_on_wrong_params

    do_something
  end

  def my_endpoint_2
    return if render_400_on_wrong_params(:myId)

    id = params[:myId]
    do_something_with id
  end

  private

  def render_400_on_wrong_params(allowed = nil)
    unsolicited_params = params.keys - Array(allowed)

    if unsolicited_params.any?
      render plain: "Unsolicited params: #{unsolicited_params.join(', ')}", status: 400
    end 
  end
end
```

It would also make sense to extract this into a [before_action](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) but the functionality will stay basically the same.

Comment: this makes sense, but it seemed likely to me that this would be handled Rails (and it would be wonky for me to do something like manually generate error messages/codes if the rails framework already supported it). do you think your implementation is conventional/idiomatic?

Comment: @ab11, the conventional approach would be to ignore the parameters. A more idiomatic approach would be a before_action like `before_action -> { render_400_on_wrong_params(:myId) }, only: [:my_endpoint_2]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `require` on the parameters

```
params.require(:myId)
```

It will raise an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception if the param is missing.

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

You can then rescue that exception on ApplicationController like this:

```
rescue_from 'ActionController::ParameterMissing' do |exception|
  render plain: '', status: 400
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html